# Tagging mail with "notmuch" marks them as old

Tags: email, offlineimap, notmuch

After syncing my local maildir inboxes with `offlineimap` and performing spam filtering and sorting using `fdm`+`bogofilter`, I tag the messages in the mail store using `notmuch`.

Up until recently, I used the following shell code to tag and re-tag messages depending on certain criteria:

```bash
notmuch new

tr -s '\t' ' ' <<'END_BATCH' | notmuch tag --batch
-inbox +sent            -- folder:/Sent/
-inbox +archive         -- folder:/Archive/
-inbox +junk            -- folder:/Junk/
+unsorted               -- folder:/INBOX.Unsorted/
-unsorted               -- not folder:/INBOX.Unsorted/
-unread -- tag:archive
+unread -- tag:unsorted
END_BATCH
```

This removes the `inbox` tag from any message in a `Sent`, `Archive` or `Junk` folder, while retagging the messages with the appropriate tags for those three folders.  It then tags or untags messages depending on whether they are in an `INBOX.Unsorted` folder (where I put messages that `bogofilter` couldn't classify).  Lastly, I ensure that archived messages are not tagged as `unread` and that unsorted messages *are* tagged as `unread`.

This worked well.

Since I receive mail on five different accounts, I then also wanted to add tags like `account-somename`, `account-othername` etc. to messages, depending on the folder name:

```
notmuch new

tr -s '\t' ' ' <<'END_BATCH' | notmuch tag --batch
-inbox +sent            -- folder:/Sent/
-inbox +archive         -- folder:/Archive/
-inbox +junk            -- folder:/Junk/
+unsorted               -- folder:/INBOX.Unsorted/
-unsorted               -- not folder:/INBOX.Unsorted/
-unread -- tag:archive
+unread -- tag:unsorted
+account-acc1           -- folder:/acc1/
+account-acc2           -- folder:/acc2/
+account-acc3           -- folder:/acc3/
+account-acc4           -- folder:/acc4/
+account-acc5           -- folder:/acc5/
END_BATCH
```

The tagging seems to be performed as expected, but a side-effect is that *new messages are marked as old* (moved from the maildir's `new` directory to the `cur` directory).  This in turn means `mutt` won't detect the new messages in the inboxes (unless I set `maildir_check_cur` in the `mutt` configuration, which I don't think is a nice solution).

I don't know why or what I could do to stop this from happening.

My `notmuch` configuration:

```
[database]
path=/home/myself/Mail/inboxes

[user]
name=myname
primary_email=me@example.com
other_email=otherme@example.com

[new]
tags=inbox;unread

[search]

[maildir]
syncronize_flags=true

[index]
header.List=List-Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen because `notmuch` is a bit too pedantic about what message files should go in what Maildir subdirectory, and because `offlineimap` is a bit too relaxed about the same thing.

The `offlineimap` utility delivers mail messages into the target Maildir's `new` directory, as expected, but the filenames have a `:2,` filename suffix, denoting "this mail message have no flags".  Usually, brand new, unseen, and just delivered message files should not have this filename suffix because it's the user's MUA (mail client) that adds it.

When `notmuch` is configured to synchronise Maildir flags (which you most likely want it to do), it notices that the message files have the `:2,` filename suffix and therefore assumes that the user must have seen the messages in their MUA, but that they have not read them (there is no `S` after the comma in the suffix).  It then moves the message files to the `cur` directory.  The `mutt` mail client consequently displays them as "old" (seen but unread).

The solution would be to correct the behaviour of `offlineimap`, but it was already [brought up as a bug and dismissed in 2015](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/issues/80).

My solution is to take `offlineimap` out of the equation.  Instead, I fetch all my mail using `fdm`.  I might look into another IMAP syncing solution later (`mbsync`?) because having a few weeks' worth of mail on the mail servers is good for accessing it away from my main machine.